SwiftUI draggable dropped item does not dissapear
I'm trying to implement drag and drop in my SwiftUI app (Xcode 16, iOS 18) but I'm seeing this weird behaviour where the dropped item would animate to the center of the drop destination, staying there a second before disappearing.

I don't see this behaviour described by Apple in the docs or in this youtube drag and drop tutorial videos (or this)
Why does the dragging item move to the center and not disappear instantly and how can I fix this?
    @State var message = "Drop It Like It's Hot"
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Text(message).padding(50)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: 300)
            .background(.green)
            .dropDestination(for: String.self) { items, location in
                if let item = items.first {
                    message = item
                }
                return true
            }

            VStack {
                Text("Item 1").padding(50).draggable("Item 1")
                Text("Item 2").padding(50).draggable("Item 2")
                Text("Item 3").padding(50).draggable("Item 3")
            }
        }
    }


I'm experiencing the same on iOS 18. Did you manage to find a workaround?

This will be fixed in the upcoming 18.1 release!
